# Average waiting time to guess a random number from $1$ to $100$ with equal probability and 1 second between each number is generated

Tags: probability

A random number between $1$ and $100$ is generated every second.
What would be the average waiting time for a specific number ($1$ for instance) to be generated?
Probability distribution is uniform.
Each number is generated independently of the others.

Comment: As you've written it, this problem is unclear.  How are the random numbers generated? (Uniformly, or from a more complicated distribution?)  Are the numbers generated independently?

Comment: The generation is independent. Probability is uniform.

Comment: 99 as a wild guess

Comment: "Between" is inclusive ? And what are your thoughts ?

Comment: Yes inclusive. Each number is generated with 1 out of 100 probability. I'm not sure about the answer - could be 99 seconds or 100 seconds...

Comment: Is the first number generated at time $0$ or at time $1$?

Comment: We can presumably agree that the mean number of *numbers* generated up to and including the first $1$ is $100$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the number of seconds until $1$ is generated:

- $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{100}$
- $P(X=1)=\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{100}$
- $P(X=2)=\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{100}$
- $\dots$
- $P(X=n)=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{100}$

So the expected number of seconds until $1$ is generated is:

$$E(X)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{100}=99$$

---

Why is it that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{100}=99$:

- $|x|<1 \implies \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$
- Differentiate each side of the equation: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$
- Multiply by $x$ each side of the equation: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$
- Use $x=\frac{99}{100}$ on each side of the equation: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n=9900$
- Multiply by $\frac{1}{100}$ each side of the equation: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{100}=99$

Comment: It's unclear to me either

Comment: I'm thinking that E(X) should be equal to the sum of probabilities that 1 doesn't appear after X-1 seconds, and it appears after X seconds, for all n=0 to infinity

Comment: @usermax: Updated the answer to explain that part.

Comment: @usermax: I wasn't thinking too much about $E(X)$, I just "went by the book" in order to calculate it, by defining a random variable first, then calculating the probability function, and finally calculating the expectancy.

Comment: Looks OK to me, I gave +1

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Thanks :) BTW, it looks like your wild guess from the comments to the question was correct... Or were you being sarcastic about it being wild?

Comment: @ barak manos No, I just followed my intuition (... which is wild :))

Comment: @barakmanos: Your computation assumes that the 1st # is generated at time 0. We could very well assume instead that it is at time 1, or time 0.5, and the question doesn't specify. Under the circumstances, I'd say it is best to take a cycle of 100 s, and compute $(t_2 - t_1)$ as the average waiting time between successive appearances of the #

Comment: @barakmanos: Following your method, if we just take 
P(X=1) = $\frac{1}{100}$, P(X=2) = $\frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100}$ etc, the expression becomes $E(X)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{100}$=100
That is the crux of the difference.

Comment: @trueblueanil: Fine, I just assumed that it would be pointless to wait a whole second before generating the first number.

Answer (score 0):

We must be careful to avoid the "fence post error"

Consider a repetitive **cycle** of 100 seconds. On an average, 1 will appear once every **100 seconds**, e.g.

**1**, 2, 3, 4, ........ 100, **1**, 2, 3, 4, ...$

[ Consider a clock. Does a minute elapse every 60 seconds or every 59 seconds ?? ]

**PS**

Here is another way to look at it. Let us replace seconds by guesses.

P[guess correctly on any try] = 1/100 = p (say)

E[average # of guesses needed to guess correctly] = 1/p = 100

Comment: Yes, 1 will appear once every 100 seconds, but we'll have to wait 99 seconds for 1 to appear.

Comment: 1-2 is 1s, 2-3 is 1s...... **100-1** is 1s (this is what you are missing). Or better still (using the clock analogy) 0-1 is 1s, 1-2 is 1s, 99-100(=0) is 1s. Do we wait 6 turns for 6 to turn up on a die or 5 ?

Comment: Let's suppose we have only one number (= 1), generated on every second. Following your reasoning, we must wait one second for number 1 to appear, which is true, but actually the "waiting" time refers the number of seconds when number 1 doesn't show up (this case 0)

Comment: So you are saying that in 2 seconds, say, the # will appear thrice ? I think more rational is to take that it appears the first time after 1 second, and appears every second thereafter.

Comment: Chronologically, you are right. But the point of the question is to statistically evaluate the distribution of number 1. It doesn't matter the time, just imagine an infinite string of numbers from 1 to 100

Comment: That's exactly the point. In an infinite stream, $(t_2 - t_1) = 100$ seconds